# Azure b2c / MVC authentication issue - OnRedirectToIdentityProvider not triggered

Tags: azure, authentication, model-view-controller

I am requested to authenticate an existing MVC web app against Azure AD B2C. Since I am new to Azure and the Azure login site is not available yet from a 3rd-party, I am trying a POC based on this tutorial project: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi.

What I did:

1. I downloaded the sample project and test it. It works as expected.
2. I copied Stratup.cs and Startup.Auth.cs from the sample to my project and all settings to web.config, almost intact. After that, when launching my project, ConfigureAuth() is called, and the home page (no auth required) can be opened.

Issue: when trying to open a page that requires authentication, the Azure login page is not launched, and I receive an Error 500 with the URL being the target URL. And, I find OnRedirectToIdentityProvider is not triggered.

I suspected that my web.config was the issue, so I copy it from my project to the sample and run the sample, it is still working. So the web.config settings should not be the problem.

The following are some sample codes. Any idea is highly appreciated.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Required for Azure webapps, as by default they force TLS 1.2 and this project attempts 1.0
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    // Generate the metadata address using the tenant and policy information
                    MetadataAddress = String.Format(Globals.WellKnownMetadata, Globals.Tenant, Globals.DefaultPolicy),

                    // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
                    ClientId = Globals.ClientId,
                    RedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,

                    // Specify the callbacks for each type of notifications
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                    },

                    // Specify the claim type that specifies the Name property.
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        NameClaimType = "name",
                        ValidateIssuer = false
                    },

                    // Specify the scope by appending all of the scopes requested into one string (separated by a blank space)
                    Scope = $"openid profile offline_access {Globals.ReadTasksScope} {Globals.WriteTasksScope}"
                }
            );
        }

public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            var userClaims = User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;
            return View();
        }

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:Tenant" value="fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <add key="ida:TenantId" value="775527ff-9a37-4307-8b3d-cc311f58d925" />
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="fdb91ff5-5ce6-41f3-bdbd-8267c817015d" />
    <add key="ida:ClientSecret" value="X330F3#92!z614M4" />
    <add key="ida:AadInstance" value="https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com/tfp/{0}/{1}" />
    <add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44316/" />
    <add key="ida:SignUpSignInPolicyId" value="b2c_1_susi" />
    <add key="ida:EditProfilePolicyId" value="b2c_1_edit_profile" />
    <add key="ida:ResetPasswordPolicyId" value="b2c_1_reset" />
    <add key="api:TaskServiceUrl" value="https://aadb2cplayground.azurewebsites.net/" />
    <add key="api:ApiIdentifier" value="https://fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/tasks/" />
    <add key="api:ReadScope" value="read" />
    <add key="api:WriteScope" value="write" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: I create a new MVC project from scratch and do the same, it works as far as this issue is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Update: find the issue - My Newtonsoft.Json v6.0 is too old, causing "hidden PII" error. Upgrading to v11.0 solves the error.